# Why there is no option to re throw the exception with custom message?

Tags: java, exception

To customize the error message, we need to do the following

- Catch the exception
- wrap the exception to another Exception
- Re throw the exception

Instead why there is no way to just change the Exception error message and re throw it?

I know it is a basic question, but curious to know your opinions.

Take an example:

```
    try
    {
        // Any operation which might throw NumberFormatException.
        int result = 1 / 0;

    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        // Observe that if I just throw by 'e' then I will get message as '/ by zero'
        throw e;

        // OR I wrap the exception (optional) and throw new exception with custom message.
        throw new NumberFormatException("<Custom Message> instead of '/ by zero'");

        // Instead, wouldn't it be easy if I could just overwrite the exception message of NumberFormatException?

        // below code isn't valid, but wondering why Java doesn't let me do this?
        e.setMessage("<Custom Message> instead of '/ by zero'");
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Because there is not a method `setMessage` in class `Exception`. You can create a class that extends NumberFormatException that call super constructor with your custom message and throw an instance of this, instead of change the message.

Comment: Yes, I know there isn't setMessage method, so I mentioned that 'Invalid code', but I am just asking why not have public setMessage method?

Comment: It can lead to inconsistent results. Say an application encounters NullPointerException and is thrown and if we reset the message as something else then the catching application might find it inconsistent. Similar to the reason why String class is final.

Comment: How does it lead to inconsistency? I will still be throwing NFE right? Ansd calling application checks for Exception type not the message in it (Generally).

Comment: All jvm generated exceptions are mapped to a specific message which is consistent across all applications. Changing the message in one application can cause the consuming application to display incorrect message for known exception types. This is the reason why the message along with the actual cause(Throwable) can be set only during construction of Exception. May be this reasoning doesnt have a good example but this is my thought.

Comment: @Anand, your thought is valid. I agree with that. All I meant is, why can't I make the message suitable for my application by not making another object (CustomException) to state that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to write some real buggy code if you could change the message of the exception. An Exception is part of the contract of a method. It reflects what happened at some point deep in the code.

It is there to communicate about something that went wrong deeper in the code. It is not your business to change this message. Either you throw the message up to some other method that can deal/understand how to go about this Exception, or you catch the exception and throw your own Exception if you so wish.

Basically the message is an intrinsic part of the Exception (immutable if you wish).

And it is also not too hard to write something like

```
catch(Exception e){
    throw new Exception("custom message" ,e);
}
```

Which is one line shorter than :

```
catch(Exception e){
    e.setMessage('my custom message');
    throw e;
}
```

Ask yourself, if your job was a messanger on a horse who has to send a letter from person A to person B, and you read the letter and realised that some additional information needed to be updated. Would you rewrite the letter and put it back in the envelope, or would you write a post-it note and stick it on the envelope?

Comment: Thanks. This is meaningful. Wouldn't I have burden of additional objects created just to rewrite(add) the message?

Comment: yes, you create another object. But these days the performance hit you get would be practically non-existant.

Comment: Imagine a memory extensive application with buggy servlet doing this check and the client hits this methods N' times a second? Wouldn't it drastically increase GC pause frequency?

Comment: The way the JVM is these days, i can't see this as a problem. A new object is created which links to an old. Objects are created all the time in code... 99.9% of the time your performance bottleneck is going to be somewhere else in your code, rather than a bit of code where you create some simple objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
 catch (NumberFormatException e){
    e.setMessage("<Custom Message> instead of '/ by zero'");
    throw e;

 }
```

This is a bad way of handling exception if `Java` let you to do so. Now you loss the original message and loss the stack trace of the exception. That's why no point of let you to set the message,and no point to catch and throw same exception, Just throw it and handle it in upper level.

If you want to do something you are trying to do, you can do it in following way

```
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    throw new MyException("your message matched with the method" ,e);
}
```

In this case you can see, both original message and `stackTrace` is preserve while you are adding your message.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that, I am just illustrating how can I customize the exception message. I may just log an error and throw back custom exception just to define my message.

Comment: yes, I can always do that, I just used NFE to illustrate it. But you see, there is a new exception we are throwing... additional coding right?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `setMessage()` meghod, you could throw a different instances of NFE but with the original exception as its cause:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new NumberFormatException("<Custom Message> instead of '/ by zero'", e);
}
```

It's important to preserve the context of the exception so the stacktrace is as useful as possible to the caller.